# Regex in R: extracting a word at the beginning of a string up to a special character

Tags: r, regex

I have a string like this "JOHN_DOE" and want to extract "JOHN". JOHN has a variable length.

I tried 
    regmatches("^[A-Z]_", "JOHN_DOE") but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `sub` to match the character `_` followed by a word and replace it with `""`

```
sub("_\\w+", "", "JOHN_DOE")
#[1] "JOHN"
```

If we have more characters followed the second word, add the `.*` to match characters that followed the word (`\\w+`)

```
sub("_\\w+.*", "","JOHN_DOE.M")
#[1] "JOHN"
```

Comment: @akurn, If I pass a string like "JOHN_DOE.M", it returns "JOHN.M". How can I solve this?

Comment: @MehdiZare  Thanks for the comment.  I updated it `sub("_\\w+.*", "","JOHN_DOE.M")
#[1] "JOHN"`

Answer (score 0):

One doesn't need stringr to do this, but I find it convenient.

Match from the start of the line `^` any upper or lower case alphabet character, zero or more times `[a-zA-Z]*` but not an underscore character `[^\\_]`

```
library(stringr)

x <- "JOHN_DOE"
str_extract(x, pattern = "^[a-zA-Z]*[^\\_]")
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the below code in order to get the desired output:

```r
str_extract(x, "^[A-z]+(?= \\_)")
```